# Baking doesn't update texture with 2.8

Tags: texture-baking

I have a simple mesh and I have materials added to it. I want to bake them to a texture. When I unwrap the mesh and click bake, it works. To have a simple texture, I decide to reset the texture and separate it between the two colors. Now when I press bake, it doesn't update. How do I fix this?

[image: UV]

This is what the UV and texture looks like. The boxes are where I want the materials to be baked and the colors are what it bakes (when it was unwrapped). Thanks for your help!

File
[image]

Comment: Can you a blend file with your settings using https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/? It is likely that you have set something incorrectly, such as the texture to bake to.

Comment: All I had to do was reopen the file and it correctly baked. I will send the file anyway. I don't think I have done anything wrong.